# Get FormData values on backend side?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Is there a way to get FormData sent from the frontend side on backend side to manage it values?

I mean something like this:

```
onFormSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { imageFile, currentGroupId } = this.state;
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('groupImage', imageFile);
    formData.set('groupId', currentGroupId);
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    };
    await axios.post('/fileUpload/group', formData, config);
  }
```

And getting it values like:

```
uploadFile(req, res) {
  const { uploadsPath } = this.porperties;
  const { formData } = req.body;
  console.log(formData.get('groupId'));
}
```

Or which alternatives can I go?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are uploading files from frontend to server try using use a module like **[multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)**.

```
let multer = require('multer');
let upload = multer();

 var storage = multer.diskStorage({
     destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads') // your path
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
 });

 var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

 app.post('/send', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
     let formData = req.body;
     console.log('form data', formData);
     res.sendStatus(200);
  });
```

Comment: Ok but do I need to pass some parameters inside `upload.fields([])` array? because it's not working :(